# Restructure JSON Payload Using XSLT

Tags: json, xslt, xslt-2.0

I have the below JSON payload, I am trying to restructure it to second format

`{ "data":{ "USDCHF:CUR":{ "PX_LAST":104.4872, "CHG_PCT_1D":0.3148063, "CHG_NET_1D":0.3279, "LONG_COMP_NAME":"Bloomberg Commodity Index" }, "BCOMPR:IND":{ "PX_LAST":217.4836, "CHG_PCT_1D":0.4914518, "CHG_NET_1D":1.0636, "LONG_COMP_NAME":"Bloomberg Precious Metals Subindex" } } }`

- Second Format:
  ` {
  "data":{
  "Ticker":{
  "Ticker_Name":"USDCHF:CUR",
  "PX_LAST":104.4872,
  "CHG_PCT_1D":0.3148063,
  "CHG_NET_1D":0.3279,
  "LONG_COMP_NAME":"Bloomberg Commodity Index"
  },
  "Ticker":{
  "Ticker_Name":"BCOMPR:IND",
  "PX_LAST":217.4836,
  "CHG_PCT_1D":0.4914518,
  "CHG_NET_1D":1.0636,
  "LONG_COMP_NAME":"Bloomberg Precious Metals Subindex"
  }
  }
  }

`

Answer (score 1):

XSLT 2.0 does not have any capability to parse or transform JSON. For that you need XSLT 3.0. Do you have access to an XSLT 3.0 processor?

There's then a problem that your desired output is invalid JSON: the value of the "data" object uses the key "Ticker" twice.

If we change the desired output to:

```
{
      "data": {
         "Ticker1": {
            "Ticker_Name": "USDCHF:CUR",
            "PX_LAST": 104.4872,
            "CHG_PCT_1D": 0.3148063,
            "CHG_NET_1D": 0.3279,
            "LONG_COMP_NAME": "Bloomberg Commodity Index"
         },
         "Ticker2": {
            "Ticker_Name": "BCOMPR:IND",
            "PX_LAST": 217.4836,
            "CHG_PCT_1D": 0.4914518,
            "CHG_NET_1D": 1.0636,
            "LONG_COMP_NAME": "Bloomberg Precious Metals Subindex"
         }
      }
   }
```

Then it can be solved in XSLT 3.0 with code such as:

```
<xsl:output method="json"/>
<xsl:template name="xsl:initial-template">
  <xsl:variable name="in" select="parse-json(...)"/>
  <xsl:map>
    <xsl:map-entry key="'data'>
      <xsl:for-each select="map:keys($in?data)">
         <xsl:copy-of select="$in?data(.) 
            => map:put('Ticker'||position(), .)"/>
      </xsl:for-each>
    </xsl:map-entry>
  </xsl:map>
</xsl:template>
```

Not tested. And note that it may produce the entries in the output maps in a different order.